# Bash Script: For each item in column 1, do something with the item in column 2

Tags: bash, loops

I am writing a bash script that reads a file and for each item in column 1, runs a command on  2-column file.  It needs to ssh into each hostname (column 1) and kill a PID (PID # in column 2).  Here's the code I'm trying, which isn't working (NOTE: this example does not run the kill command but asks script to ps the PID):

```
while read host pid; do
        /usr/bin/sshpass -f ~/.pw /usr/bin/ssh -q  -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o ConnectTimeout=5 $host ps -ef| egrep -e $pid
done < $UNIQ_FILE
```

The $UNIQ_FILE is formatted like this:

```
192.168.22.199  55829
192.168.22.142  662
...
```

The script is running the command on the first line of the file, and then exits.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/584427/bash-script-loop-through-a-file

Answer (score 0):

You need to use -n option in your ssh command

> -n      Redirects stdin from /dev/null (actually, prevents reading from stdin).  This must be used when ssh
> is run in the background.  A common trick is to use this to run X11 programs on a remote machine.
> For example, ssh -n shadows.cs.hut.fi emacs & will start an emacs on shadows.cs.hut.fi, and the X11
> connection will be automatically forwarded over an encrypted channel.  The ssh program will be put
> in the background.  (This does not work if ssh needs to ask for a password or passphrase; see also
> the -f option.)

```
while read host pid; do /usr/bin/sshpass -f ~/.pw /usr/bin/ssh -n -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o ConnectTimeout=5 $host ps -ef| egrep -e $pid done < $UNIQ_FILE
```